# Angular DI. OpenAPI generated code not working if loaded as external module

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, openapi

I generated a simple OpenAPI Angular code for a web service client out of OpenAPI YAML as described here:

https://github.com/cyclosproject/ng-openapi-gen

It works perfectly fine if the module is generated inside the same Angular project. It stops working, if I pack the generated code into a separate project and download it from the NEXUS server referencing from `package.json`.

Here is an Angular application module (`app.module.ts`), which uses the generated ApiModule:

```
import { ApiModule  } from '../../generated/ts/api.module'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ApiModule
  ],
  providers: [ ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Here is the `app.component.ts`:

```
import { ApiService } from '../../generated/ts/services/api.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root', templateUrl: './app.component.html', styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'demo';
  hello: any;

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {  }

  public sayHello() {
    this.apiService.helloworldGet().subscribe((e: HelloWorld200) => {
      this.hello = e;
    });
  }
}
```

After moving the code to the external module, the import statement changes to

```
import { ApiService } from 'api-service-project/generated/ts/services/api.service';
```

Everything else stays the same. Same code, same YAML, same eager/lazy behavior. Only the generated code is located in `node_modules` instead of project directory structure. It prints following string into the browser console:

```
ERROR Error: ASSERTION ERROR: token must be defined [Expected=> null != undefined <=Actual]
```

----------------------------  (some more files as asked in comments)

`package.json` of Api Service

```
 {
  "name": "api-service-project",
  "version": "1.1.2",
  "description": "Demo API",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Tests are not written yet\" && exit 0",
    "generate:api": "ng-openapi-gen --input ./src/main/resources/api.yaml --output ./generated/ts",
    "prebuild": "npm run generate:api",
    "build": "npm pack"
  },
  "files": [
    "./generated/ts",
    "./src/main/resources/api.yaml"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/core": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^15.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^7.4.0"
  },
  "author": "...",
  "license": "ISC",
  "publishConfig": {
    "registry": "https://nexus..."
  },
}
```

`package.json` of Frontend Application

```
{
  "name": "frontend-application",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^15.0.0",
    "api-service-project": "^1.1.0",  // <------ the API module
    "rxjs": "^7.4.0"
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.0.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~15.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.5.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.8.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please include `package.json` of your `api-service-project` npm module?

Comment: Also, do you have some `paths` configuration in your `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: Both projects (API and Frontend App) are fresh generated minimalistic projects. No "paths" records in "tsconfig.json".

Comment: How exactly did you package api module? I guess you should package as angular library, not as simple node package. See https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you found a solution yet?